# Maintain volume with remotely connected bluetooth speaker

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-audiomanager

please any one can give me suggest this is possible or not.

I creating an app for music in which i connect my app with Bluetooth speaker. Its connect well and playing also, But my question is that when we press volume + - button of speaker then tablet/phone volume also + - . is it possible or not.

If yes then plz guide me .

Answer (score 0):

If the Bluetooth speaker's volume button follow the standard Bluetooth media event.I think you can do so.

Just take a look at this:

*https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html*

Comment: Hi ifeegoo, I already tried the broadcast receiver but its never call when i press volume button of remotely connected speaker volume button